# Creating a dll from a java .war file

Tags: java, .net, dll, war

I have an external tool that is a tomcat webservice (distributed as a .war) that I would like to use from .net.  I have a fairly complex environment and I would like to not have to deal with adding more moving parts (tomcat, java, etc) to the production machines.  Is there a way to convert the app to a dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the only option you have is to deploy the WAR in a Java environment and then call it from your .NET environment.

I can recommend Jetty for deploying the WAR, I have had much better experiences than using Tomcat. It's simpler, starts up faster, the errors are easier to understand. (But obviously any Java web container will do.)

Then call your Java service from your .NET code. It seems like the Java code already offers a web service, so  you need to build a client for that in .NET. If it uses a standard web service protocol like SOAP there should be lots of libraries available for .NET to allow you to do that.

There is no quick automatic way to convert Java into .NET alas; so this is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

`.dll` are totally windows specific things where `.war` is totally jvm specific thing.

I don't think you will find tool / converter for it.

I would suggest consume web Services from your .net

Answer (score 0):

Utterly impossible. Be glad that having this tool as a webservice means you *only* need a JVM and a servlet container to use it, rather than having to rewrite it completely. When it comes to application integration, this is a very easy case.